# cocapods do not download the version 2.3 of core plot

Tags: swift, cocoapods, core-plot

I tried to install Core Plot with cocoapods but it always downloads the version 2.2 and not 2.3. The following line I typed in my Podfile

```
pod 'CorePlot', :git => 'https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot.git', :branch => 'release-2.3'
```

But cocopoads still downloads and installs the version 2.2. Are there any syntax errors ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you determining the version? The changelog on that branch hasn't been updated yet and still says "Release 2.2". An easy way to check is to look at `CPTXYAxis`. If the `xConstraints` and `yConstraints` properties are public, you have the code from the `release-2.3` branch.